# Controlling Toggled States

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have a strange question.

I've created two squares slightly overlapping.  When you click one square, its width extends via toggle.  What I would like to do is create a function that watches for if the event has been triggered and if so, to change the z-index of the second element to be above the first.  Is this possible?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/theodore_steiner/qvc7da0s/9/

```
<div id="square1"></div>
<div id="square2"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#square1
{
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-color: blue;
position: absolute;
z-index: 3;
transition: all .4s ease;
 }

 #square1.active
 {
 width: 50px;
 }


#square2
{
height: 20px;
width: 20px;
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
left: 25px;
 }
```

JS;

```
var square1 = document.getElementById("square1");
var square2 = document.getElementById("square2");


square1.onclick = function pushLeft()
    {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS rule, which use the [general sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

If one might only want the immediate sibling, use the [adjacent sibling selectors `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

```
#square1.active ~ #square2
{
  z-index: 5;
}
```

Sample snippet

```js
var square1 = document.getElementById("square1");
var square2 = document.getElementById("square2");

square1.onclick = function pushLeft() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
};
```

```css
#square1 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
#square1.active {
  width: 50px;
}
#square1.active ~ #square2 {
  z-index: 5;
}
#square2 {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square1"></div>
<div id="square2"></div>
```

Comment: So the line #square1.active ~ #square2 the "~" is essentially saying if square1 is active do this to square 2? Also, in general is there a method method in JS to check if an event has fired?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner Yes, using the [sibling selector `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner How you mean check if an event is fired? ... Your `onclick` event does exactly that, when fired it tell you someone clicked.